# splitting line in proper way

Tags: perl

```
if($line =~ /^HWI.*/)
{
    my @fields=split ":",$line;
    $id= $fields[5].":".$fields[6];
    print $fields[5]," ",$fields[6]; <>;
    $id =~ s/\s+//;
    $hash1{$id}=$line;
  }else{
    $hash1{$id}.= $line;
  }
```

hi all this is the script that is supposed to print only 5th and 6th fields seperated by ':'

My input is something like this:

```
HWI-1KL120:99:C0C9MACXX:6:1101:2105:2123    0   chr5    75483987    0   82M3I16M    *   0   0
```

i want only 2105 2123 i,e 5th and 6th fields but this is printing entire line starting from 2105 2123

How to get only those fields?

Comment: Cross-posting IMO identifies an OP with no patience!

Comment: Doesn't bother me as much if there's at least a mention that the question has been cross-posted to ... (along with a link).  At least then the reader can benefit from the collaborative effort that may be going on at the other forum.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with cross posting or any judgements to be made about OP that does cross-posting... though as DavidO mentions, just make sure to mention it so people can work off of both resources.

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead.

```
...
my @fields = split /[:\s]/, $line;
$id = qq{$fields[5]:$fields[6]};
print "$fields[5] $fields[6]";
$hash1{$id} = $line;
...
```

This splits on `:` **and** on `whitespace`, therefore separating field entry #6 (if this is  feasibly in your problem).

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the problem is that you are splitting on colons and not on whitespace.

Instead of using `split`, find all the sequences of characters that are neither colons nor whitespace like this

```
  my @fields = $line =~ /([^:\s]+)/g;
```

The rest of your program should work OK, although the line `$id =~ s/\s+//` removing whitespace from `$id` is unnecessary, and I am troubled by the stray `<>` at the end of the `print` statement. This will read and throw away the next line from the file, which I presume it is deliberate, but it should be on a line on its own and not hidden away like that where it could easily be missed.

Answer (score 0):

`split` on white-space or a colon like this:

```
perl -le '$line=qq(HWI-1KL120:99:C0C9MACXX:6:1101:2105:2123 0 chr5 75483987 0 82M3I16M * 0 0);@F=split /[\s:]/,$line;print join q( ),$F[5],$F[6]'
2105 2123
```

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting the line on colons, and there's no colon after 2123 so `$fields[6]` (the seventh field, remember indexes are zero based) is `2123 0 chr5 75483987 0 82M3I16M * 0 0`.

You might be better off doing it all in the initial regular expression:

```
if($line =~ /^HWI[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:(([^:]*):(\S*))/) {
  $id = $1;
  $id =~ s/\s+//;
  $hash{$id} = $line;
  print "$2 $3", <>;
} else {
  $hash{$id} .= $line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my @fields=split /:|\s+/, $line;
```